# Calendar hide/show works no more with Extensible 1.5 and ExtJS 4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have ported an existing Extensible calendar-app to Extensible 1.5 with ExtJS 4.1. Since then a calender cannot be hidden/shown anymore when clicking on it or using the context-menu for only showing the selected calendar.

After extensive research I found the relevant place and bugs in the code:
`extensible-all-debug.js:4559 rec.set([CM.IsHidden.name], !isHidden);`. It will add a new attribute `0: "IsHidden"` to `rec.data`, which definitely cannot be correct. When changing to `rec.set(CM.IsHidden.name, !isHidden);` it works but I am in no way interested in hacking the Extensible code.

I found out that the 'TestApp'-Example of Extensible uses ExtJS 4.0.7 where everything works fine. I changed  the `Extensible-config.js` to use ExtJS 4.1 by changing the extJsRoot to 'http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.0-gpl/'.
Now 'TestApp' is using ExtJS 4.1 and is broken too (hide/show won't work anymore), so there is definitely a bug, maybe Extensible but I think its more related to ExtJS 4.1 because as I stepped into the rec.set-Method of both versions (4.0.7 and 4.1) they seem to differ very much, so it could be that ExtJS 4.1 breaks something Extensible relys on.

To reproduce the Bug:

1. Change extJsRoot in `Extensible-config.js` to 'http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.0-gpl/'
2. Open 'TestApp' locally.
3. Add a break-point at `extensible-all-debug.js:4559`.
4. Show/Hide a calendar.
5. Break-point hit, one step further.
6. Inspect rec.data, should have a new attribute `0: "IsHidden"`.
7. Continue script, calendar won't get hidden/shown.

Comment: Bugreport exists already in Extensible Forums: http://ext.ensible.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=570

Answer (score 1):

I posted a work around for this issues to the support forum at http://ext.ensible.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=570

Gabe